# How to search properly using keyword in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I can not search the value from Database putting the key word using PHP and MySQL. Here is my code:

```
$searchKey=$_GET['searchKey'];
$special_id=$_GET['special_id'];
$city_id=$_GET['city_id'];
$day_id=$_GET['day_id'];
$keyword = '%'.$searchKey.'%';
$data=array();
$sql =mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM  db_restaurant_basic  WHERE rest_name LIKE '".$keyword."' and special='".$special_id."' and city='".$city_id."' and status=1 GROUP BY member_id ORDER BY member_id DESC ");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $data[]=array("restaurant_name"=>$row['rest_name']);
    }
}
$result=array("data"=>$data); 
echo json_encode($result);
```

When i am calling the following URL to get the result.

```
http://localhost/spesh/mobileapi/categoryproduct.php?item=2&acn=5&special_id=1&city_id=1&day_id=4&searchKey=on
```

Its giving me the following result.

```
{"data"[{
   "restaurant_name":"Sonoma on 9th"
},{
    "restaurant_name":"Jamesons Irish Pub 17th Ave. SW"
},{
   "restaurant_name":"Jamesons Irish Pub Brentwood NW"
},{
    "restaurant_name":"National on 17th"
}
]
}
```

My problem is I need to search the `Restaurant name` which contains the keyword `on` but I am getting some other `Restaurant name` which doesn't contain keyword `on`. I need when user will search the restaurant name using keyword `on` it should give the restaurant name which contains that word `on` only not other restaurant name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using keyword "like" in your query which search "on" everywhere in restaurant name.

you should use spaces to make it specific

```
$keyword = '% '.$searchKey.' %';
```

check the spaces after first % sign and before the second one

Answer (score 2):

add blanks around the keyword:

```
$keyword = '% '.$searchKey.' %';
```

By the way: Learn abut prepared statements to prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: Tough luck. You answered first, but OP still picks the other one. Upvoted you.

Comment: @LoganWayne Not the first answer should be accepted. The best answer should be accepted and maybe the other is better.

Comment: Looks the same to me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using direct substitution values, you could use below methods to avoid sql injection.

You basically have two options to achieve this:

Refer [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

For example, using MySQLi (for MySQL):

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Please refer How can [I prevent SQL-injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)?